# Lost PostgreSQL Superuser Username and Password

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4 database running on Windows, but I've lost the name of the superuser username, so am unable to connect.

I've already configured `pg_hba.conf` to use `trust` to allow connections without a password, but I still need to know the name of a valid user to login.

I've tried *postgres*, *admin* etc, but I always get:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "USERNAME" does not exist
```

Comment: Hmm, there should be 'postgres' user - it's there by default and it's  hard to remove it, as it owns a lot of system tables/views/templates. Is that exact message you are getting? Is "USERNAME" being replaced by actual username you're entering?

Comment: "USERNAME" is being replaced by the actual username :)

Comment: Ok, sorry - just checking. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to run PostgreSQL in single-user mode. On my system (Linux), I've been able to get  superuser sql shell with following command: `sudo -u postgres postgres90 --single postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.0/data/`.

`sudo -u postgres` here is to drop priveledges (postgres refuses to run under priveledged account`, other params should be easy to understand.

In single-user shell you should be able to create new user or `SELECT * FROM pg_user;`

Comment: Perfect, I was able to start the server in single-user mode, then use that to create a new superuser role

Comment: +1 Incidentally, this solved my problem of creating roles headlessly in a Vagrant provisioning script (i.e., `sudo -E -u postgres createuser --createdb --login --superuser vagrant; sudo -E -u postgres createdb vagrant`).